# The map $f$ is degenerate or non-degenerate?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, bilinear-form

Let denote by $M_{3,2}(\mathbb C) $ the space of all $(3\times2)$-matrix of complex-dimension equal  $6$ with basis $(E_{1},E_{2},E_{3},E_{4},E_{5},E_{6})$. Let $f$ a $\mathbb R$-bilinear skew-symmetric map given by  $$\begin{array}{crcl}
f : &M_{3,2}(\mathbb C)  \times  M_{3,2}(\mathbb C) & \longrightarrow& M_{2,2}(\mathbb C)\\
&(A,B)  & \longmapsto  &f(A,B) = i(A^{*} B - B^{*} A),
\end{array}$$ where $M^{*}$ denote the conjugate transpose of a matrix $M$ (i.e., $M^{*}= \, ^{t}\bar{M} $).

I like to know is what $f$ is degenerate or non-degenerate ?

**Recall that:** a $\mathbb R$-bilinear map $f :V \times V \longrightarrow W$ is $$\mbox{non-degenerate} \, \Leftrightarrow \, \forall x\in V, \mbox{if} \, f(x,y)=0, \,  \forall \, y\in V,\, \mbox{then} \, x=0\, \Leftrightarrow\, \ker{f}=\{0\}, $$ where $\ker{f}=\{x\in V / \, f(x,y) = 0 \, \mbox{for all}\,  y\in V \}$ the kernel subspace of $f$.

Noted that in our case: $\ker{f}=\{A\in M_{3,2}(\mathbb C)/ \, A^{*} B =B^{*} A  \, \mbox{for all}\,  B\in M_{3,2}(\mathbb C)\}$

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V, W$ are vectors spaces over the same field $K$ and $B$ a
base of $V$, a bilinear map $f:V\times V\rightarrow W$ is
nondegenerate iff there is no $v\not=0$ in $V$ s.t $f(v,e)=0 $ for
all $e\in B$.

So $f$ is well a $\Bbb{R}$-bilinear map, normaly if we
want to check that $f$ is nondegenrate we must resolve $f(A,e)=0$ for all $e $ in
the canonical real bases of $M_{32}(\Bbb{C})$ as $\Bbb{R}$-vector space. But in
this particular  case it is enough to solve it for
  $e\in S=\{E_{ij}, i=1,2,3 \;j=1,2\}$ the canonical
 $\Bbb{C}$-base of $M_{32}(\Bbb{C})$, because   $f(A,E_{ij})=0$ for all
$E_{ij}\in S $ get  then  $A=0$. So  by resolving this 6 matricial
equation we get  that $A$ must be $0$,and so $f$ nondegenerate
bilinear map .

Example of resolving: fixe a variable matrix as $A=\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & t \\
y & u \\
z & v
\end{array}
\right) $ if we resolve   $f(A,E_{11})=f(\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
x & t \\
y & u \\
z & v
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 \\
0 & 0
\end{array}
\right))=0$  we arrive that $t=0$

and also if we resolve   $f(A,E_{12})=0$  we arrive that $u=0$. So
on we come to the conclusion that $A=0$ and $f$ nondegenerate.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much m.idaya

Comment: because u is a lineaire sum of e  and f lineare on the second variable we have for some v f(v,e)=0 for all $e\in B$ is equivalent to f(v,u)=0 for all u